# Django caching: Fetching a queryset in context_processor

Tags: django, performance, caching

I have a queryset fetching specific notification objects for users to display in a custom context_processor. Now I'm wondering whether this could be a performance issue? If it is, can I somehow enable caching of data maybe 1 hour or 1 day from now on?

Should I do some custom caching or is django supported caching of objects enough?

Answer (score 1):

I will suggest you to use default [cache](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/cache/#basic-usage) and store a notification string itself (not an object). So you will be doing query once.

Another good solution will be using [messages framework](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/messages/).